# Can I grab data from a datagrid row when the UserDeletedRow event is triggered

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is populated from a dataset but not bound to I.
I would like to retain the user being able to delete rows in the datagrid and have these trigger the UserDeletedRow event for the grid, but I still need to capture some information from the Row so that I can run the SQL to remove it from the database.

My question is can you add any variables to the sub routine that allow you to pull out some information from the row being deleted (even one cell would be enough) or alternatively does anyone know if the UserDeletedRow event is triggered on the hit of the delete key but before the row is removed completely from Datagrid object; and so the row is still "selected" and accessible; or after the row has been removed.

Kind regards

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which I will leave here for others.
Within the subroutine there is a variable 'e' which holds information about the row triggering the event.

You can gather anything you like from the this row as it appears to have the same property options as a DataGridRow object.

Below is a sample of the code where you can pull out a single cell (in this case a rowID) and store the data for use before it is fully removed.

```
Private Sub dgvCalibration_UserDeletedRow(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs) Handles dgvCalibration.UserDeletedRow

    Dim intDelRow As Integer
    intDelRow = e.Row.Cells(0).Value()
```

Matt